# Did India ever look to Russia for HAL Tejas's engine?

Tags: russia, india

Recently, India signed a deal with the USA for a GE F404 engine for HAL Tejas.

Given the lengthy and deep ties India has with Russia, did India ever look to Russia for a jet engine for HAL Tejas?

If not, why?

Comment: I don't think India has that deep of a tie with Russia in practical terms. Su-30MKI is such a good platform that could serve them another 2 decades with modernization, but got totally abandoned instead. See how Pakistan is dressing up their JF-17 like Christmas trees with all those gadgets with the help from Chengdu. Are the Russians willing to work on either the MKI or Tejas? Are the Indians willing to pay what the Russians ask for? Not so much.